# How to return str representation of non- Ascii letters in python

Tags: string, python-2.7, python-unicode, representation

I have a code snippet that can separate  Portuguese texts from numbers. The code is:

```
import re
def name():
    text = u'Obras de revisão e recuperação (45453000-7)'
    splits = text.split(u" (")
    return(str(splits[0].encode("utf8")))
name()
```

and the output is:`'Obras de revis\xc3\xa3o e recupera\xc3\xa7\xc3\xa3o'`

but when I write

```
print(splits[0].encode("utf8"))
```

the output would be: `Obras de revisão e recuperação` which is my desired result.

but it doesn't work with the return function. I read the [difference between `__str__` and `__repr__`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/difference-between-str-and-repr-in-python), but still, I am clueless how to get the same output as `__str__`  with the return inside a function.

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work ? What happens ? What do you expect to happen ?

Comment: Just wrap your function within `print()`. E.g: `print(name())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overthinking this. You  use a `unicode` literal to make your `unicode` object, and then your `splits` list will contain `unicode` objects:

```
In [4]: def name():
   ...:     text = u'Obras de revisão e recuperação (45453000-7)'
   ...:     splits = text.split(u" (")
   ...:     return splits
   ...:

In [5]: splits = name()

In [6]: splits
Out[6]: [u'Obras de revis\xe3o e recupera\xe7\xe3o', u'45453000-7)']
```

When a `list` is printed to the screen, the `__repr__` of the objects contained in the `list` is used. However, if you want the `__str__`, just use `print`:

```
In [7]: for piece in splits:
   ...:     print(piece)
   ...:
Obras de revisão e recuperação
45453000-7)
```

Note, `.encode` **returns a byte-string**, i.e. a regular, non-`unicode` Python 2 `str`. Calling `str` on it is essentially the identity function, it's already a `str` when you `encode` it:

```
In [8]: splits[0].encode('utf8')
Out[8]: 'Obras de revis\xc3\xa3o e recupera\xc3\xa7\xc3\xa3o'

In [9]: str(splits[0].encode('utf8'))
Out[9]: 'Obras de revis\xc3\xa3o e recupera\xc3\xa7\xc3\xa3o'
```

You should really, really consider using Python 3, which streamlines this. `str` in Python 3 corresponds to Python 2 `unicode`, and Python 2 `str` corresponds to Python 3 `bytes` objects.

So, to clarify things, your `name` function should work like this:

```
In [16]: def name():
    ...:     text = u'Obras de revisão e recuperação (45453000-7)'
    ...:     splits = text.split(u" (")
    ...:     return splits[0]
    ...:

In [17]: print(name())
Obras de revisão e recuperação
```

Comment: @mk_sch I don't understand what the problem is, then? Fundamentally, your issue was you were doing `print(splits[0].encode("utf8"))` when you don't *ever need to `.encode` your `unicode` objects*

Comment: @mk_sch no problem. I went ahead and added it to my answer.